# Broken Site due to Incorrect ASP .NET Core Query Usage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to get my website built with Swagger in ASP .NET Core to work, however, I'm having some trouble (maybe some confusion?) as to how to specify query parameters. This specific API calls seems to break the site and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the API call:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/v2/config/get_metadata/{name}/from?f={from}/to?t={to}")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    [SwaggerOperation("GetMetadata")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(Metadata), description: "successful operation")]
    public virtual IActionResult GetMetadata([FromRoute][Required] string name,
      [FromQuery] DateTime from, [FromQuery] DateTime to)
    {
      //TODO: Uncomment the next line to return response 200 or use other options such as return this.NotFound(), return this.BadRequest(..), ...
      // return StatusCode(200, default(Dataset));

      //TODO: Uncomment the next line to return response 400 or use other options such as return this.NotFound(), return this.BadRequest(..), ...
      // return StatusCode(400);

      string exampleJson = null;
      exampleJson = "{}";
      exampleJson = "";

      var example = exampleJson != null
      ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Metadata>(exampleJson)
      : default(Metadata);
      //TODO: Change the data returned
      return new ObjectResult(example);
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong so if anyone can spot the error, please let me know! I suspect it's how I've defined the route or how I've used `FromQuery` but I can't get it to work :(.

`from` and `to` are also meant to be optional filters.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to specific the query parameter in Route Attribute,dose Alexander's answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

The route is invalid, as it contains two question marks and an unescaped slash '/' in the query part
A possible valid route could be:

```
/v2/config/get_metadata/{name}
```

In order to use the querystring parameters (?f={from}&to={to}), you can indicate `[FromQuery]` before the parameter

Comment: This throws an exception.

Comment: The literal section '?f=' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character. '

Comment: @bob123123123123 you are correct, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The value in `Route` is incorrect, it shouldn't contains query parameters and `?` sign. Something like this will work for requests like `/v2/config/get_metadata/{name}?from={from}&to={to}`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/v2/config/get_metadata/{name}")]
public virtual IActionResult GetMetadata([FromRoute][Required] string name, [FromQuery] DateTime? from, [FromQuery] DateTime? to)
```

`from` and `to` are optional due to used nullable type `DateTime?`. You can also merger `HttpGet` and `Route` and achieve the same result

```
[HttpGet("/v2/config/get_metadata/{name}")]
```